# Can "Bar" be placed center of vertical grid line in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

My current project needs to show this kind of graphics chart.

Most of the time a `Bar` element is at the middle of 2 vertical grid lines, but in my case, it should be at the center of 1 vertical grid line.

I searched sample codes and API documents, but I couldn't find a solution for my case.

Is it possible to draw this kind of chart with Chart.js? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to set gridLines.offsetGridLines to false? It should be working fine. Check out the documentation here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#scale-configuration

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        offsetGridLines: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I read that config in the document, but I couldn't get it clearly. You saved my day.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? I tried `offsetGridLines: false` and it works well, however, the result is slightly different from my expected image. Each grid line needs to have the same distance from another, but `offsetGridLines: false` makes trim off(?) start and last grid line, so the distance has half-width size. (Sorry, since my English is not professional, it is hard to describe my situation well.)

Comment: If possible could you show me the data and the chartjs configuration you are currently working on? xAxes do have settings for `categoryPercentage`, `barThickness` and `barPercentage` for adjusting bar size and the gap between categories. If you do have more than 1 category and want them to be stacked instead of placed next to each other, you could set `stacked: true` as well. Read more about scale for xaxes: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I solved with this config: `options > scales > xAxes > offset: false` It is a little bit frustrating that this config is not even in the API document.